# C Linked List memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

I can't figure out why my linked list has a memory leak.

I have a method called `insertAtFront()`

```
void insertAtFront(Node **head, char *key) {
    Node *new =  malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!new)  fatal("Malloc of new Node failed");
    new->word = key;
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}
```

Then I have a `removeAtFront()` method that frees the node.

```
void removeAtFront(Node **head) { 
    Node *newhead = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = newhead;
}
```

If I only add one node and then remove it, there is no leak. If I remove more than one node, valgrind shows a leak proportional to how many additional nodes were added. I really can't understand why this happens as the node is freed. Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough code shown to comment. You need to show how/when/where those methods are called.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that shows the problem. It's not possible to tell what the problem is from this incomplete code.

Comment: Note: `Node * newhead = (*head)->next;` should not occur if `*head == NULL`.

Comment: `free( *head );` occur before free'ing `(*head)->word` , was that was needed?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a life cycle issue.  You did not post the calling code and a complete verifiable example.  The nodes are correctly freed, but there is something that is not. Is the `key` argument allocated and not freed elsewhere?

You do not `free` the `word` member when you free a node.  If the `key` argument was allocated by the function that called `insertAtFront()`, it should be free'd with the node.  If the `word` field is allocated only some of the times, it is difficult to determine when to free it.

A good solution is for `insertAtFont()` to always duplicate the `key` string and for `removeAtFront()` to always free the `word` member:

```
void insertAtFront(Node **head, const char *key) {
    Node *new =  malloc(sizeof(*new));
    if (!new)  fatal("Malloc of new Node failed");
    new->word = strdup(key);
    if (!new->word)  fatal("Malloc of Node key failed");
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}

void removeAtFront(Node **head) {
    Node *node = *head;
    if (node) { 
        *head = node->next;
        free(node->word);
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Note that it could be convenient for `insertAtFront()` to return a pointer to the newly inserted node at no cost.

Comment: How do you know `key` was dynamically allocated without seeing a more complete code snippet?

Comment: @John3136: I don't *know* that, I made a supposition and wrote *seems to be*.  It is a common problem to be imprecise about object life cycle and the symptoms are consistent with my proposal. Let's see if the OP confirms this. I modified the answer to indicate the reasoning behind this proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks chqrlie! Freeing the word seems to do it.  Sorry all for the lack of code, I was just trying to pull out only the part that was causing the problem.